# SFDX: Tests do not run in Visual Studio Code

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, visualstudiocode

I am relatively new to SFDX and have the most recent updates for both VSCode and Salesforce CLI.

I am unable to run any Apex tests on a sandbox using the UI in Visual Studio Code.  When doing so I get the following output

`sfdx force:apex:test:run --tests Plan_XXXX_ControllerExt_Test.testxxxxController --resultformat human --outputdir c:\Users\xxxxxx\Documents\xxx\xxxxx\.sfdx\tools\testresults\apex --loglevel error
ERROR:  Unable to invoke async test job: Cannot read property '1' of null.`

When running that directly from the CLI I get the following

`WARNING: In salesforcedx v41 and earlier, the --resultformat parameter caused the apex:test:run command to wait for test results rather than finishing immediately and returning a test run ID. In salesforcedx v42 and later, the --resultformat parameter will no longer cause the command to wait. To wait for test results, include the --wait parameter.
ERROR:  Unable to invoke async test job: Cannot read property '1' of null.`

However, if I run the tests without the --resultformat tag through the CLI I am able to get back test results.

e.g. -

`sfdx force:apex:test:run --tests Plan_XXXXX_ControllerExt_Test.testxxxxController --outputdir c:\Users\xxxxxx\Documents\xxx\xxxxx\.sfdx\tools\testresults\apex`

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved by changing the proxy settings in Windows environment variables.

**Previous**

HTTP_PROXY = http://username.password@company.proxy.com:8080

HTTPS_PROXY = http://username.password@company.proxy.com:8080

**FIX**

HTTP_PROXY = http://company.proxy.com:8080

HTTPS_PROXY = http://company.proxy.com:8080